# LTspice simulation with multiple transistor in single package

Tags: transistors, simulation, ltspice

[Here](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds30347.pdf) is the transistor using for LTspice circuit simulation.
But it comes as package with PNP and NPN.
Here is the link of the [model](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwig7ujOp_PRAhUBMY8KHXfdDpwQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diodes.com%2F%3Fq%3Ddownloads%2F141915%2Fspice&usg=AFQjCNGx79uHjB3pxGaE56iZpKBmcKNwJA&bvm=bv.146094739,d.c2I) as well.

How can I use single transistor alone for simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 models in the file, one for PNP transistors and one for NPN. Both models have the same name (DI_DCX144EU), but if you use the standard PNP or NPN symbol LtSpice should pick the correct one.

The biasing resistors in the real device (R1 and R2) are not included in the spice model, you need to add these to the schematic using the appropriate values from the datasheet.

Comment: added the model for pnp alone by editing the model in the LTspice and fixed the issue. Thanks for the response.